# How do I properly publish an application from visual basic 2010 express for use on a different PC?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce, publish, vb.net-2010

As the title says, I have a program written in VB.net 2010. When I use the publish feature it creates a manifest and setup file that install the program nicely on another PC, but I think the security settings are somehow wrong because it sits there for ninety seconds upon launch. The program works fine on the computer that built it. There is no CPU usage while it is sitting around. Thoughts?

Comment: Does this program have any dependencies? If not, you can simply copy the exe from your Release directory and then use it on another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to:

1) Make sure the target machine has the (correct version of the) .NET framework installed

2) Copy the `[Project name].exe` and any dependant `.dll` files from your `[Project name]\bin\Release` folder into a folder on the target machine

3) Double click the `[Project name].exe`

Alternatively you could have a look at [OneClick Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx) but this requires some form of web server and so may be overkill for your application (and I'm not sure if this is available in express edition)